# Merge multiple rows from a function's return data into the middle of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, spread

I want to merge the rows returned from a function call directly into (the middle of) the declaration of a larger array.

The challenge is that the function is returning multiple rows.  Is it possible to inject multiple rows into the expected 2d structure?

Sample input/code:

```
function some_function() {
    return [
        ['id' => 'thing2', 'type' => 'sample'],
        ['id' => 'thing3', 'type' => 'sample']
    ];
}

$ztest = [
    ['id' => 'thing1', 'type' => 'sample'],
    some_function(),
    ['id' => 'thing4', 'type' => 'sample'],
    ['id' => 'thing5', 'type' => 'sample']
];
print_r($ztest);
```

Desired result:

```
[
    ['id' => 'thing1', 'type' => 'sample'],
    ['id' => 'thing2', 'type' => 'sample'],
    ['id' => 'thing3', 'type' => 'sample'],
    ['id' => 'thing4', 'type' => 'sample'],
    ['id' => 'thing5', 'type' => 'sample']
]
```

But no matter what I try, I can only ever end up with:

```
[
    ['id' => 'thing1', 'type' => 'sample'],
    [
        ['id' => 'thing2', 'type' => 'sample'],
        ['id' => 'thing3', 'type' => 'sample']
    ],
    ['id' => 'thing4', 'type' => 'sample'],
    ['id' => 'thing5', 'type' => 'sample']
]
```

I've tried array_map, array_filter, array_values, array_merge... nothing seems to work.

This seems simple enough and I feel like it should be possible to do, but I can't figure it out.

Note: I'm aware that I could do an array_merge with these two arrays after the fact, or insert it after the fact, but for the sake of code cleanliness in the project I'm working on, I'd prefer to do it inline.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:
`array_merge_recursive`
here is sample code:

```
   <?php 
    function some_function(){
    $items = array();

    $items[] = array(
        'id'                => 'thing2',
        'type'              => 'sample',
    );

    $items[] = array(
        'id'                => 'thing3',
        'type'              => 'sample',
    );

    return $items;
}


$ztest = array(
    array(
        'id'                => 'thing1',
        'type'              => 'sample',
    ),

    array(
        'id'                => 'thing4',
        'type'              => 'sample',
    ),
    array(
        'id'                => 'thing5',
        'type'              => 'sample',
    ),
);
$result = array_merge_recursive($ztest, some_function());
echo "<pre>";

print_r($result);
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks so much for taking the time to respond. Yes, this will definitely work, but what I'm curious about is if there's a good way to do it inline, like I outlined above. The "real" code I'm working with on this project makes it a bit cluttered and janky to do it the way you've outlined here. Do you know of any way to do that?

Comment: I edited the code, I remove the variable that contains the second array and made the array merge them in one line, I guess this is the best approach and will take one extra line from you to get it done.

Comment: This is the only line you need to add to your code, 
`$result = array_merge_recursive($ztest, some_function());`

Comment: In the real deployment, it's not this simple. The arrays are nested within a large class declaration, and also need to be output in a specific order, since they are being used for a wordpress options menu framework that just runs down the list of options. So the approach you've outlined here is not ideal.

Comment: In this case, you will have to manually write it, I have the code that sort the multi-dimensional arrays, but you said you are not willing to use multiple lines of codes.

Comment: Gah, ok. That's too bad. I know laravel has a function that does this basic thing when working with their collections, so I had hoped it would do doable with native php, but it sounds like perhaps not.

Comment: Laravel has it as custom function written by someone then it was included on their framework, but PHP has no direct function to do that,

Answer (score 0):

```
function some_function(){
    $items = array();

    $items[] = array(
        'id'                => 'thing2',
        'type'              => 'sample',
    );

    $items[] = array(
        'id'                => 'thing3',
        'type'              => 'sample',
    );

    return $items;
}

$ztest = array_merge(some_function(), array(
    array(
        'id'                => 'thing1',
        'type'              => 'sample',
    ),
    array(
        'id'                => 'thing4',
        'type'              => 'sample',
    ),
    array(
        'id'                => 'thing5',
        'type'              => 'sample',
    ),
));
```

Then, if you need to sort items of array by `id` field - use `usort` function:

```
usort($ztest, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['id'], $b['id']); });
```

Comment: Thanks, u_mulder. This certainly makes sense, but do you not know of a way to directly insert that other array's children without using array_merge and usort?

Comment: Directly - no. Also you can use `foreach` to iterate over one array and add each item of this array to new array with `[]`.