# PHP Write "an array of arrays" dynamically inside an array of arrays, while declaring it

Tags: php, arrays, return

In the middle of declaring an array of arrays, I want to "write" an array of arrays generated by my function.

I have a working example when I:

1. simply store my function-generated arrays into a variable and
2. then call each array from that function by its key,

but I can't find a command to simply call everything at once.

Here is the code which (I hope) explains it:

```
<?php

// A. (THIS WORKS)

// A1: A function that returns an array of arrays
function my_arrays_building_function() {
    $first_array = array(
        'id'        => 'my_array_1',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
        'title'     => 'My title 1',
    );
    $second_array = array(
        'id'        => 'my_array_2',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
        'title'     => 'My title 2',
    );
    // ... and so on, many more.
    return array(
        'first-array' => $first_array,
        'second-array' => $second_array,
        // ... and so on.
    );
    // NOTE there are tens or hundreds of returned arrays here.
}


// A2: Store my arrays in a variable
$my_array = my_arrays_building_function();


// A3: Inside an array (of arrays), I simply "write" my arrays INDIVIDUALLY and THAT works
array(

    array(
        'id'        => 'dummy_preexisting_array_1',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
    ),

    array(
        'id'        => 'dummy_preexisting_array_2',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
    ),

    // HERE THERY ARE, INDIVIDUALLY, COMMA SEPARATED
    $my_array[ 'first-array' ],
    $my_array[ 'second-array' ],

    array(
        'id'        => 'dummy_preexisting_array_n',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
    )

),

/** -------------------- //
        THE ISSUE
// -------------------- **/

// B: HOW DO I "write" THEM ALL AT ONCE???

// B1: The same as A1
function my_arrays_building_function() {
    $first_array = array(
        'id'        => 'my_array_1',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
        'title'     => 'My title 1',
    );
    $second_array = array(
        'id'        => 'my_array_2',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
        'title'     => 'My title 2',
    );

    // NOT SURE I SHOULD RETURN LIKE THIS
    return array(
        'first-array' => $first_array,
        'second-array' => $second_array
    );
}

// B2: Same as A3, Inside an array (of arrays), I "write" my arrays BUT NOW I WANT TO "WRITE" THEM ALL AT ONCE
array(

    array(
        'id'        => 'dummy_preexisting_array_1',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
    ),

    array(
        'id'        => 'dummy_preexisting_array_2',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
    ),

    /** >>>> I need my arrays here ALL AT ONCE aka NOT INDIVIDUALLY AS IN EXAMPLE A. <<<< **/
    /** 
     * In other words, while I'm declaring this array, 
     * I simply need all my arrays from my_arrays_building_function() 
     * "written" here with a simple command instead of calling hundreds
     * of arrays individually as in the first example
     */

    array(
        'id'        => 'dummy_preexisting_array_n',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
    )

), /* this goes on as it's a part of even bigger array */
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Merge multiple rows from a function's return data into the middle of a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51760224/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Rylee for suggesting [Array Unpacking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.unpack-inside-array).

The final code would look like this:

```
// C1: A function that returns an array of arrays BUT without keys
function my_arrays_building_function() {
    $first_array = array(
        'id'        => 'my_array_1',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
        'title'     => 'My title 1',
    );
    $second_array = array(
        'id'        => 'my_array_2',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
        'title'     => 'My title 2',
    );
    // ... and so on, many more.

    // Then return but now I don't assign keys, I only list the vars.
    return array(
        $first_array, $second_array, ... and so on.
    );
}

// C2: Inside an array (of arrays), I use Array Unpacking, THAT'S WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR, UNPACK ARRAY! SEE BELOW
array(

    array(
        'id'        => 'dummy_preexisting_array_1',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
    ),

    array(
        'id'        => 'dummy_preexisting_array_2',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
    ),

    // HERE I UNPACK MY ARRAY BY USING ... THE THREE DOTS ARE THE KEY
    ... my_arrays_building_function(),

    array(
        'id'        => 'dummy_preexisting_array_n',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
    )

),
```

Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

- Although I wouldn't recommend declaring hundreds of array variables inside a function because that's crazy, but for now, you can use [`get_defined_vars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) to get over this issue.
- You will also need to filter out the variables which are arrays and has the keys `id`, `type` and `title` as there are could be several other variables defined apart from this.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

array_filter(get_defined_vars(), fn($val) => is_array($val) && isset($val['id'], $val['type'], $val['title']));
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yh5ejcnz)

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this'll do because my arrays are all different and not all contain and only contain 'id', 'type' and 'title'.

Comment: @oneone Bad practice to declare hundreds of array variables to begin with. You will need to show the possible keys for those arrays then.

Comment: Thank you @nice_dev but Rylee suggested [Array Unpacking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.unpack-inside-array) and it worked. Thank you again for your suggestion.

Comment: @oneone I am still confused what you wanted in the first place but glad you solved it.

Comment: I also recommend [unpacking the returned payload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843413/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if I'm understanding this correctly but from what I assume, you just want to return an array with a bunch of others inside it that you define throughout the function?

A simple approach for this would be to define your output variable immediately and add all of your other arrays to it:

```php
function my_arrays_building_function() {
    $output = [];

    $output[] = [
        'id'        => 'my_array_1',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
        'title'     => 'My title 1',
    ];

    $output[] = [
        'id'        => 'my_array_2',
        'type'      => 'some-type',
        'title'     => 'My title 2',
    ];

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: OK, but nothing happens when I call it in the "I need my arrays here" part. If I say:
`$myvar = my_arrays_building_function();`
and then while declaring the master array I do this:
`$myvar,`
Nothing happens, if I echo (or print_r) the code ends up in the frontend and not as the actual part of the master array.

Comment: @oneone I don't think your question is clear enough. If you want to merge arrays, you can use `array_merge` which combines elements from multiple arrays. If you want to insert an array inside another existing one, use `array_splice`. You can also look at [Array Unpacking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.unpack-inside-array) for PHP7.4+. If you need to **define** an array with nested arrays, simply include them as array elements.

Comment: Array Unpacking, That's it! The three dots of doom ffs. Thank you! The unpacking worked but the prep is a bit different from the one in your comment so I'll have to post the solution comment. But how can I upvote you or send thanks or something like that?